# Visualizing self-balancing binary tree (AVL-tree)

Tags: java, tree, binary-search-tree, avl-tree, depth

I have written an application for visualizing a binary search tree. Now I am attempting to modify it to visualize a **self-balancing** binary search tree. I have the balancing methods, but there seems to be some problems with updating the *depth* and *index* vars in each node, which are used to calculate the draw position of the nodes. The code is getting quite difficult to wrap my head around after trying a bunch of different things, but I suspect there is a simple solution, so I thought i'd ask here.

Example run: Input nodes 50, 60, 70. Tree should look like this:

```
60(depth = 0, index = 1, height = 1, size = 2), 
50(depth = 1, index = 1, height=0, size = 0) and 
70(depth = 1, index = 2, height = 0, size = 0)
    60
  50  70
```

But instead, it looks like this:

```
50(depth = 0, index = 1, height = 0, size = 0)
60(depth = 1, index = 2, height = 2, size = 2)
70(depth = 2, index = 4, height = 0, size = 0)
50
  60
    70
```

```
public void setDrawPosition(Node node) {
        node.drawX = (node.index * DrawPanel.width) / ((int)Math.pow(2,node.depth) + 1);
        node.drawY = node.depth * DrawPanel.height / (depth+1);
    }
    
    public void addNode(int val) {
        root = addNode(val, root);
        System.out.println("tree depth is now: " + this.depth);
        root.height = this.depth;
    }
```

Here's the addNode-method:

```
private Node addNode(int val, Node node) { 
        if (node == null) {
            return new Node(val, 0, 0, 1, 0); // Node(int val, int depth, int size, int index, int height)
        }
        if (val < node.key) {
           node.left = addNode(val, node.left);
           node.left.depth = node.depth + 1;
           if(node.left.depth > this.depth) {
                depth = node.left.depth;
                root.height = node.left.depth;
            }
           node.left.parent = node;
           node.left.index = (node.index*2)-1;
           if (height(node.left) - height(node.right) == 2) {
               if (val < node.left.key)
                   node = rotateWithLeftChild(node);
               else
                   node = doubleWithLeftChild(node);
           }
           
        } else {
           node.right = addNode(val, node.right);
           node.right.depth = node.depth + 1;
           if(node.right.depth > this.depth) {
                depth = node.right.depth;
                root.height = node.right.depth;
            }
           node.right.parent = node;
           node.right.index = (node.index*2);
           if (height( node.right ) - height( node.left ) == 2) {
               if (val > node.right.key) 
                   node = rotateWithRightChild(node);              
               else 
                   node = doubleWithRightChild(node);
           }
        } 
        node.height = max( height( node.left ), height( node.right ) ) + 1;
        node.size++;
        return node;
    }
```

One of the simple rotations (they are similar):

```
   private Node rotateWithRightChild(Node k1) {
       Node k2 = k1.right;
       k1.right = k2.left;
       k2.left = k1;
       k1.height = max( height( k1.left ), height( k1.right ) ) + 1;
       k2.height = max( height( k2.right ), k1.height ) + 1;
       
       return k2;
   }
```

Comment: I would advise not to store all that information, and to derive it dynamically on a need-to-know basis. Some things can be derived easily. For instance in a breadth-first traversal, the depth and index are trivial to keep track of incrementally during the traversal.

Comment: @trincot So I should only initialize left, right and parent in addNode, and calculate the other variables like depth, index, size and height in separate methods, and then call those methods before i draw the tree?

Comment: That is what I would suggest. I would even try to go without a parent reference. When drawing the tree you could call a method that will return the height of the whole tree. With that information you can do a next traversal to actually draw the tree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to not store this extra information with the nodes, as it can be a pain to keep that information updated. Instead determine this information dynamically whenever you need to draw the tree.

For instance, you could keep only `val`, `left` and `right` as properties of a `Node` instance, and define a recursive method to calculate the height of the current node. Then the actual drawing method could use that to get the overall height of the tree, and use a breadth first traversal to get all other needed information to draw the tree.

Here is some code that does a simplified "draw": just an output line by line, but using appropriate indents. I think it should be simple to adapt to your drawing mechanism:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

class Node {
    int val;
    Node left;
    Node right;

    Node(int val) {
        this.val = val;
        left = right = null;
    }

    Node add(int val) { 
        return val < this.val
           ? left != null ? left.add(val)
                          : (left = new Node(val))
           : right != null ? right.add(val)
                           : (right = new Node(val));
    }

    int getHeight() {
        return 1 + Math.max(
            left == null ? 0 : left.getHeight(),
            right == null ? 0 : right.getHeight()
        );
    }

    void draw() {
        int colWidth = 5;
        int height = getHeight();
        int colDistance = (int) Math.pow(2, height);
        ArrayList<Node> level = new ArrayList<Node>();
        level.add(this);
        while (colDistance > 0) {
            ArrayList<Node> nextLevel = new ArrayList<Node>();
            String line = "";
            int col = colDistance / 2 - 1;
            for (int i = 0; i < level.size(); i++) {        
                Node node = level.get(i);
                if (node == null) {
                    nextLevel.add(null);
                    nextLevel.add(null);
                } else {
                    if (col > 0) { // pad string
                        line = String.format("%-" + (col*colWidth) + "s", line);
                    }
                    line += Integer.toString(node.val);
                    nextLevel.add(node.left);
                    nextLevel.add(node.right);
                }
                col += colDistance;
            }
            System.out.println(line);
            level = nextLevel;
            colDistance /= 2;
        }
    }
}
```

Demo use:

```
    Node root = new Node(40);
    root.add(50);
    root.add(30);
    root.add(20);
    root.add(60);
    root.add(35);
    root.draw();
```